# methods to get website loading time for each step during execution of selenium scripts?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm working on an automation using selenium, but the application on which I'm testing was not always good, I need to get the response for the elements to load on each page so I can clearly get the actual execution time of the script. Is there any way to get such results?

Comment: This question is not really a good fit for this site. It's also been asked a lot here and elsewhere. Did you google this before asking here? Selenium is really not the best tool to do things like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to record the HTTP traffic to create a HTTP Archive (HAR) and analyse this.

[this](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/page-load-analysis-using-firebug/) link could be worth a read